# JavaScript behaviour with blocking code

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function simulateComplexOperation(sleepDuration) {
  var now = new Date().getTime();
  while (new Date().getTime() < now + sleepDuration) { /* do nothing */ }
}

function testFunction() {
  document.getElementById('panel1').style.display = 'none';
  console.log('before');
  simulateComplexOperation(2000);
  console.log('after');
}
```

```html
<div id='panel1'>
  text to hidden
</div>

<button onclick="testFunction()">Hide</button>
```

([jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yqo11r9c/1/))

This is the timeline:

- Prints "before"
- wait 2 seconds
- Prints "after"
- hide element with id 'panel1'

Why is it not:

- hide element with id 'panel1'
- Prints "before"
- wait 2 seconds
- Prints "after"

Is there a way to force a style change operation to be the first?

Comment: because of how the browser schedules rendering

Comment: Use [WebWorkers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) to do background work.

Comment: Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37092024/3865670

Answer (score 0):

You would preferably use setTimeout. But it's caused by the scheduling of the code by the browser.

```js
function simulateComplexOperation(sleepDuration) {
  var now = new Date().getTime();
  while (new Date().getTime() < now + sleepDuration) { /* do nothing */ }
}

function testFunction() {
  document.getElementById('panel1').style.display = 'none';
  console.log('before');
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('after');
  }, 2000);
}
```

```html
<div id='panel1'>
  text to hidden
</div>

<button onclick="testFunction()">Hide</button>
```